# plot elements of array with different colors

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I have a vector of integers that vary from 1 to 4.

```
A=[1 2 3 4 2 3 2 1 2 3 4 4]
```

I would like to plot A with different colors for each value...
the vertical line that links A(1) to A(2) should have the color of the first value (in this case 1).

Is that possible?

and how to handle the case of NaN present in the vector?
I should plot A against a time vector

```
A = [1 1 1 NaN 4 4 4 Nan 2 2 3 3];
time = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the following set of colors:

```
col = hsv(4);
```

You set the order of the colors based on the values of A:

```
figure();
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', col(A,:), 'NextPlot', 'replacechildren');
```

Then, you can plot each line in the desired color:

```
n = numel(A);
plot(hankel(0:1,1:n-1),hankel(A(1:2),A(2:n)))
```

This results in:

[image]

---

**Edit:**
The `hankel` approach is a bit like shooting with a bazooka to kill a mosquito, as we say in the Netherlands. Anyway, I learned about it a few questions ago - so I liked to use it. See the post of Dan for a simpler alternative for the plotting. Still, setting the correct colors can be done as in the above.

Comment: A combination of the two is probably best. You aren't using `hankel` to set the colours correctly, that's done earlier so you can just call `set(gca, 'ColorOrder', col(A,:), 'NextPlot', 'replacechildren');` and then still use my `plot(x,y)` and skip the `hankel` but still get what you're calling the right colours

Comment: In the included picture of the figure, the last straight line (on the right) is not included. But I can assure you, it is really there ;)

Comment: thanks! I edited the question because I was getting an error with this test case..

Comment: Should the NaN values be omitted, or do they need a distinct color?

Comment: They shouldn't be plotted..ideally I should have an empty space, the time sequence should be preserved...is there a function like hsv to select different markers in order to plot with different colors and different markers?

Comment: you can use `col(A(~isnan(A)),:)` instead of just `col(A,:)` to correctly avoid that error

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using just a touch of trickery:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 2 3 2 1 2 3 4 4]

x = [1:numel(A)-1; 2:numel(A)];
y = A(x);

plot(x,y)
```

[image]